# Strange "go to sources" behaviour in VS

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

This is what I get when I select "go to definition" in the ConfigTests.cs. But I expected to go to already opened Config.cs with actual declaration.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added a normal assembly reference.
When you Go to Definition on a member not defined in your project (or in Project References), Visual Studio will generate a source file from metadata using Reflection.

Delete the reference, then re-add it as a Project reference (in the Projects tab).
If the project isn't in the same solution, put it there.

Comment: Yes... My colleague added reference to a library, not to a project :-S Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This seems to indicate that your reference to the `Models` assembly is via the compiled DLL, not via the project in the solution. Try the following in the Solution Explorer:

- Expand (unfold) the “References” item of the main project in your solution.
- Select “Models” and press Delete to remove it.
- Right-click on “References” and choose “Add Reference”.
- Select the **Projects** tab (*not* the **Browse** tab).
- Highlight the *Models* project and click OK.

Of course, this assumes that the *Models* project is in your solution to begin with. If it isn’t, you will first have to add it by right-clicking the first item in the Solution Explorer (the Solution itself), choosing “Add”, “Existing Project”, and then choosing the right `csproj` file for the *Models* project.